# Vue.js: Accordion is not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, accordion

I added accordion for a single item and it was working fine, but then I added in for loop and now when I click on any item, all items are getting expanded.

```
<template>
<ul class="level-0-wrp" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
    <li class="level-0" v-for="(menu, index) in headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items" :key="index" :class="accordionClasses" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
        <a class="title" @click="toggleAccordion">{{ menu.item_name }}</a>
        <ul class="level-1-wrp" v-if="menu.childrens">
            <li class="level-1" v-for="(submenuone, indexone) in menu.childrens" :key="indexone" v-if="menu.childrens">
                <a class="title">{{ submenuone.item_name }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            isOpen: false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        toggleAccordion () {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        accordionClasses () {
        return {
            'is-closed': !this.isOpen,
            'is-primary': this.isOpen,
            'is-dark': !this.isOpen
        };
        }
    }

}
```

As given in this picture, If I click on men, women, and accessories get expanded.

[image]

Comment: your applying isOpen to all, there is only one state, you need to make it an array of states, or set it on the menu model if its open or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

You can add another data property `selected: ''`, then in template toggle accordion `v-if="isOpen && menu.item_name === selected"`. In method you set selected:

```
toggleAccordion (item) {
  item == this.selected ? this.isOpen = !this.isOpen : this.isOpen = true
  this.selected = item
}`
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data () {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      selected: '',
      headerDesktopMenu: {
        menu: {
          menu_items: [{item_name:11111, childrens: [{item_name: 11}, {item_name: 12}]},{item_name:22222, childrens: [{item_name: 21}, {item_name: 22}]},{item_name:33333, childrens: [{item_name: 31}, {item_name: 32}]},{item_name:44444, childrens: [{item_name: 41}, {item_name: 42}]}]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAccordion (item) {
      item == this.selected ? this.isOpen = !this.isOpen : this.isOpen = true
      this.selected = item
    }
  },
  computed: {
    accordionClasses () {
      return {
        'is-closed': !this.isOpen,
        'is-primary': this.isOpen,
        'is-dark': !this.isOpen
      };
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="level-0-wrp" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
      <li class="level-0" v-for="(menu, index) in headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items" :key="index" :class="accordionClasses" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
          <a class="title" @click="toggleAccordion(menu.item_name)">{{ menu.item_name }}</a>
          <ul class="level-1-wrp" v-if="menu.childrens">
              <li class="level-1" v-for="(submenuone, indexone) in menu.childrens" :key="indexone" v-if="isOpen && menu.item_name === selected">
                  <a class="title">{{ submenuone.item_name }}</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `@click="toggleAccordion"` to all items. To fix your problem, every item needs it own state. This, for example, could be done like that:

First, provide your state as an `object`:

```
return {
            isOpen: {}
        }
```

As I don´t know the structure of your data, I just did this example with a simple `array` of `objects` like this:

```
testObject: [
        {name: "hello1"},
        {name: "hello2"},
        {name: "hello3"},
        {name: "hello4"}
      ]
```

Just loop trough this in `created` to generate a state for all, like this:

```
for(let itemId in this.testObject) {
      Object.assign(this.isOpen, {[itemId]: false})
    }
```

The `object` `isOpen` now looks like this:

```
{
   "0":false,
   "1":false,
   "2":false,
   "3":false
}
```

Now you can call `toggleAccordion` with the `index` from your loop, like `toggleAccordion(index)` and change the function to this:

```
toggleAccordion(index) {
      this.isOpen[index] = !this.isOpen[index];
    }
```

Where you applied `isOpen` before you just apply `isOpen[index]` now.